# Can't get a simple printing vba script to run

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Print3()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If .Name <> "CHART OVERALL" Or "CHART TL" Or "CHART BL" Or "CHART TR" Or "CHART BR" Then

    Else
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            cht.Activate
            ActiveChart.PrintOut Copies:=1
        Next cht
    End If
Next sht

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I can't seem to get this to work. I've tried a lot of variations of this code and I'm not sure why it's not working as it's fairly simple. For each of the worksheets I name in the If statement, I'd like the print the charts in those sheets. Any thoughts?

Comment: I haven't quite gotten to this step yet, but I'd also like to be able to choose which sheets to print based on values of another sheet. But first I need to get this down...

Comment: sht.name <> x or sht.name=y or sht.name=z....

Comment: you want to add this little beaut at the end for certs: Application.ScreenUpdating = True    Won't get very far without that...

Comment: Did you make sure your active printer is set to the one you expect?

Comment: Yes. I can run the two for loops with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement needed some work, added the screen updating = true too...

```
Sub Print3()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If .Name <> "CHART OVERALL" and .Name <> "CHART TL" and .Name <>  "CHART BL" and .Name <>  "CHART TR" and .Name <>  "CHART BR" Then

    Else
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            cht.Activate
            ActiveChart.PrintOut Copies:=1
        Next cht
    End If
Next sht

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True
application.screenupdating = true
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an "invalid or unqualified reference" error.

Comment: Hopefully my answer will help, but i was getting this error because i needed to use sht.Name to get the name of the sheet and couldn't just use .Name

Answer (score 1):

So I modified a couple things. For the if statement, I think it was registering true for you all the time, possibly due to .Name not getting the sheet name, and therefore you were never getting into your else statement. Here is the modified code.

```
Sub Print3()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = "CHART OVERALL" Or sht.Name = "CHART TL" Or sht.Name = "CHART BL" Or sht.Name = "CHART TR" Or sht.Name = "CHART BR" Then
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            Debug.Print sht.Name
            cht.Activate
            ActiveChart.PrintOut Copies:=1
        Next cht
    End If
Next sht

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```